# Script Not Working to Move Row into new Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like a script to move a row from one sheet to another (within the same workshop) based on a TIME TRIGGER rather than onEdit (because onEdit doesn't work with IMPORTRANGE).

I found a script that worked brilliantly on edit:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Active
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  // getColumn with condition is currently set to column 12 or L
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Active" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "8") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);

  }
}
```

and a few that could work on time triggers and then combined/manipulated them to get this:

```
function PushToCompleted() {
  // assumes source data in sheet named TEST
  // target sheet of move to named Test2
  // getColumn with condition is currently set to column 12 or L
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19WFdvLlWE-oI0OT8c6uBmgu2jSvdX0upM9nobscn5G4');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName("TEST");
  var r = ss.getDataRange();;

  if(ss.getName() == "TEST" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "8") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = ss.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = sss.getSheetByName("Test2");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);

  }
}
```

I then went in to set up the time trigger to every minute. But it's not working- not on manual run nor with the every minute time trigger. I'm VERY new with scripts, so would imagine there's something wrong within the script.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Are you sure your condition gives you true? What if you add an `else` case just to test your function invocation where you would set some test value in a random cell of your choice?

Comment: onEdit trigger only fires on User Edits.

Comment: Your conditional: `if(ss.getName() == "TEST" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "8")` will only fire under the following conditions: 1. the sheet `ss` has a name `TEST` (which it does) AND 2. the data range of sheet `ss` *starts* on column `L` (which it doesn't, `r.getColumn()` will return `1` as r is the data range of sheet `ss`). What are you trying to get from range `r`? Or from sheet `ss`?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo If column #12 (L) has the number 8 in it, then i want the entire row to me moved to sheet Test2. That makes sense that I've set the data range wrong, but how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Your conditional statement is always evaluating to false, and so the code within the `if` block is never being executed.*

#### More Information:

As per the Apps Script [documentation on the `Sheet.getDataRange()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange):

> Returns a [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) corresponding to the dimensions in which data is present.
>
> This is functionally equivalent to creating a `Range` bounded by A1 and (Range.getLastColumn(), Range.getLastRow()).

This means that when you call `ss.getDataRange()`, you are getting the *entire range in which data is present*, starting at `A1`. If we go another step further and check out the [documentation for `Range.getColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn):

> Returns the starting column position for this range.

That means that for a `Range` object, obtained by using the `Sheet.getDataRange()` method, `getColumn()` will ***always*** return 1.

As well as this, as you need to do this for each row and check the value in column L for each, you need to put your check inside a loop.

#### Fix:

From your comment:

> If column #12 (L) has the number 8 in it, then i want the entire row to me moved to sheet Test2.

Instead of simply getting the data range and directly comparing the column value in your conditional, you need to check the whole L column for cells that contain the value 8 and copy those rows:

```
function pushToCompleted() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var originSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TEST");
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test2");
  var range = originSheet.getDataRange()
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var count = 1;
  values.forEach(function(row) {
    if (row[11] == "8") {
      targetSheet.appendRow(originSheet.getRange("A" + count + ":" + count).getValues()[0])
      originSheet.deleteRow(count);
      count--;
    }
    count++;    
  });
}
```

Run down of this code:

- Set your origin and target sheets to variables
- Get the whole data range of your origin sheet
- Set a counter for the current row you're looking at
- Loop through each row of your data range and check column L for the value 8:

  - If the value of the cell in column L is `8`, then append the whole row to Sheet `Test2`
  - Delete the row from the origin sheet
  - Also readjust the counter as now your origin sheet now has one less row

#### References:

- [`Sheet.getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [Class Range | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [`Range.getColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn)
- [`Sheet.appendRow(rowContents)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: One problem- The script is deleting ALL the data in Test sheet rather than JUST the data with an 8 in the row. It only moves the data with an 8 to the Test2 sheet. But ALL data is removed from Test sheet. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: @ErinE Can you share your sheet so I can take a look? I copy+pasted this script directly from my test environment where it works without issue

Comment: I tried it in a test sheet as well and it worked perfectly there. I think the problem is that I'm using IMPORTRANGE to fill the row with data. So when the row that has the IMPORTRANGE gets deleted/moved, then everything else disappears. I suppose a workaround for this could be a dummy line that has the IMPORTRANGE there with no 8, so it's never moved?

Comment: Yes, the issue with IMPORTRANGE is that the data comes from elsewhere. An alternative is have a second sheet which just takes the display data from the `IMPORTRANGE` and run your function off of this. The original data would stay in the `IMPORTRANGE` but will cease messing up when the lines are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Active" && e.range.columnStart==12 && e.value=="8") {
    var targetSheet= e.source.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(target);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

You can't run this script from the script editor unless you supply the event object.

[onedit event obj](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

> onEdit(e) runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.